# AngularJS - Email error message on Textbox Blur

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have implemented AngularJs email validation as below :-

```
<div class="control-group" ng-class="{'has-success': contactform.contactemail.$valid && submitted,'has-error': contactform.contactemail.$invalid && submitted }">
     Email
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactemail" name="contactemail" ng-model="user.contactinformation[0].email" />
    <p class="help-block" ng-show="contactform.contactemail.$error.email">Not valid email!</p>
</div>
```

But as the user start typing his email in the Textbox, Error Msg gets displayed instantly which doesn't look good.

How to show error msg at time of user leaving the textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ng-blur:

```
      <div ng-form="contactform" class="control-group">
          Email
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactemail" ng-blur="validate=true" name="contactemail" ng-model="email"  />
          <p class="help-block" ng-show="contactform.contactemail.$error.email && validate">Not valid email!</p>
      </div>
```

Set `validate=true` on the blur event, and only show the error message when email is invalid and `validate=true`.

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way would be to use a custom trigger `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"`:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="contactemail" 
           ng-model="email" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" /><br />
```

This will only trigger the model update on the 'blur' event which is probably the thing you are lookng for

Comment: Given the nature of ngModelOptions, the value displayed inside input fields in the view might be different than the value in the actual model. This means that if you update the model you should also invoke $rollbackViewValue on the relevant input field in order to make sure it is synchronized with the model and that any debounced action is canceled.